# Inner join on LIKE sqldf

Tags: r, inner-join, sqldf

How can I use the `LIKE` clause with an inner join using sqldf in R?

The code:

```
Name <- c("Jack","Jill","Romeo")
Name <- as.data.frame(Name)
FullName <- c("School Jack H", "School Juliet G", "College Jill M", "College Romeo F")
Marks <- c("100","82","54","0")
FullBio <- cbind(FullName, Marks)
FullBio <-as.data.frame(FullBio)
```

And then when I run:

```
sqldf("select a.*, b.* from Name a join FullBio b on a.Name like '%'+b.[FullName]+'%'")
```

returns 0 rows.

Why? What are my other alternatives please. I apologise for making you create so many variables to run my code.

Comment: hey can u mention the desire output of your question.

Comment: @user2923027 There is no need to use `cbind`. Just using `FullBio <- data.frame(FullName, Marks)` is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string concatenation operator is `||` in SQLite:

```
sqldf("select * from Name join FullBio on FullName like '%' || Name || '%'")
```

giving:

```
   Name        FullName Marks
1  Jack   School Jack H   100
2  Jill  College Jill M    54
3 Romeo College Romeo F     0
```

Any of these would also work:

```
sqldf("select * from Name join FullBio on instr(FullName, Name)")

sqldf("select * from Name join FullBio on like('%' || Name || '%', FullName)")
```

Comment: It did not work for me. Im on a Macbook and Im hitting the key next to "]" with shift. I tried this before and it didnt work.
Edit: It worked. But it does not work when I use qualifiers like a and b. Do you know why?

Comment: It works for me.  Copy the code from the answer and paste it into R just to be sure you haven't made a typo.  Also make sure sqldf is working by trying a very simple query:  such as `sqldf("select * from BOD")`