# fuzzy join with sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf, fuzzy-comparison

I was expecting this code to return a `data.frame` with `name` = `helicase` in row 1. How can I make this type of comparison with `sqldf`?

```
require(data.table)
df <- fread('EC              name
    2.1.1.233       helicase
    4.1.3.3         phosphatase
    1.3.2.1,2.5.4.1 lipase
')
df2 <- fread('     PDB     EC         
    1uay    2.1.1
    5ad4    4.1.3.3   
')


require(sqldf)

sqldf('
select  df2.*
        , df.name
from    df2
        left join df
          on df2.EC like df.EC
')

#    PDB      EC        name
# 1 1uay   2.1.1        <NA>
# 2 5ad4 4.1.3.3 phosphatase
```

Comment: What is the default `drv` in your case as I get error with the code `Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such column: df2.EC`

Comment: @akrun how do I find that?

Comment: Ok, I think the example is creating V1, V2 as column for df2 as there are some white space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34333574/7600300), you want to concatenate the percent signs:

```
sqldf("
select  df2.*
        , df.name
from    df2
        left join df
          on like('%'||df2.EC||'%', '%'||df.EC||'%')")
```